# Assembly variables are deleted (16 bit x86 assembly)

Tags: variables, assembly, x86

I'm still playing with retro programming in turbo C for MS-DOS, and I found some trounble using variables.

If I define some variables at the start of the assembly code (in BSS or DATA), and try to use them inside the assembly function, most of the time these variables are deleted, or end up containing random data.

I learned a bit of assembly for the game boy :) and variables always worked well and never were deleted or modified, I guess x86 asm is different.

Then I tried this using inline assembly and it was a bit better, there is just one variable (width) not working.

```
void draw_map_column(MAP map, TILE *t){
    word *tiledata = &t->data;
    int *mapdata = map.data;
    int width = map.width<<1;
    word tile_offset = 0;
    word map_offset = 0;
    word screen_offset = 0;
    asm{
        push ds
        push di
        push si

        mov     dx,12       //column

        lds     bx,[tiledata]                   
        lds     si,ds:[bx]              //ds:si data address
        mov     [tile_offset],ds
        mov     [tile_offset+2],si

        les     bx,[mapdata]
        mov     ax,es:[bx]
        mov     cl,8
        shl     ax,cl
        add     si,ax
        mov     di,screen_offset        //es:di screen address                          
    }
    loop_tile:
        asm{
        mov     ax,0A000h
        mov     es,ax
        mov     ax,16
    }
    copy_tile:  
    asm{
        mov     cx,8
        rep     movsw               
        add     di,320-16
        dec     ax
        jnz     copy_tile

        mov     ds,[tile_offset]
        mov     si,[tile_offset+2]

        mov     ax,map_offset
        add     ax,[width]        //"width" does never contain the value stored at the start
        mov     map_offset,ax

        les     bx,[mapdata]
        add     bx,ax
        mov     ax,es:[bx]
        mov     cl,8
        shl     ax,cl
        add     si,ax

        dec     dx
        jnz     loop_tile

        pop si
        pop di
        pop ds
}
```

}

Just note the "witdh" variable which is not working at all, if I replace it with a number (40), the code just works as expected (this draws a column of tiles using a map array, and some tiles stored in ram).

I guess it has something to do with the push/pop etc, and something is not set as it should.

Also what happens in pure assembly? none of the variables were working. I defined them as DW and also added:

```
push bp
mov bp,sp

;function 

mov sp,bp
pop bp
```

Thanks.

Comment: `width` is a local variable on the stack hence it needs to be accessed as `[bp+offset]`. Use a disassembler to see what the compiler emits for `[width]`. Maybe you need to write `[bp+width]`. Changing `ds` definitely breaks all your global variables, no surprise there. Don't do that :)

Comment: So ds destroys variables... so many things I don't know. thanks!

Comment: @Jester for inline assembly the C compiler will fill `[width]` in with `[bp+widths_offset_from_bp]` if width were a local variable. As well he's using the large memory model so all pointers are FAR

Comment: Something I do find suspicious in your code is that when you write FAR address (segment and offset) to pointer variables it seems you are storing it backwards. The offset is stored at the lower word and the segment is stored at the higher word. For example `mov     [tile_offset],ds` `mov     [tile_offset+2],si` should be (I think) `mov     [tile_offset+2],ds` `mov     [tile_offset],si` . This applies toall the other caes where you do the same thing.

Comment: I also thought the same, but that was copied from the disassembler of a c function that ws working, (and it worked).

Comment: Do you ever use the debugger to step to this code and look at what is in the registers and if the segments are what you expect?

Comment: Actually now I see something here that makes no sense as I look closely. You define `tile_offset` as a `word` (2 bytes) value . But your inline assembly seems to treat it as a pointer. You update tile_offset+2 which likely is the offset of `width` on the stack and that causes width to be clobbered.

Comment: I believe this line is destroying the contents of the variable `width`: `mov     [tile_offset+2],si` . If you were to stick a dummy `word` variable between `tile_offset` and `width` at the top of your function I bet you would get a different result. You need to properly handle data types.

Comment: Thanks I think thats the problem, I still need some practice. with data types and pointers. If I understand it well, I'm destroying variables because I'm not defining well ttheir sizes and they are overlaping in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well once again thanks a lot, next time I'll be more patient before asking.

Just in case this is useful for someone, I had defined a variable using the wrong size.
There are other things that can be improved, but that's another question.

Variable "tileoffset" holds a 32 bit address, so it must be a "dword", not a "word". Then the function should be like this:

```
void draw_map_column(MAP map, TILE *t){
    word *tiledata = &t->data;
    int *mapdata = map.data;
    int width = map.width<<1;
    dword tile_offset = 0;  //changed to dword to store 32 bit address
    word map_offset = 0;
    word screen_offset = 0;
    asm{
        push ds
        push di
        push si

        mov     dx,12       //column

        lds     bx,[tiledata]                   
        lds     si,ds:[bx]              //ds:si data address
        mov     word ptr[tile_offset],ds //store a word
        mov     word ptr[tile_offset+2],si

        les     bx,[mapdata]
        mov     ax,es:[bx]
        mov     cl,8
        shl     ax,cl
        add     si,ax
        mov     di,screen_offset        //es:di screen address                          
    }
    loop_tile:
        asm{
        mov     ax,0A000h
        mov     es,ax
        mov     ax,16
    }
    copy_tile:  
    asm{
        mov     cx,8
        rep     movsw               
        add     di,320-16
        dec     ax
        jnz     copy_tile

        mov     ds,word ptr[tile_offset]  //read a word to the register
        mov     si,word ptr[tile_offset+2]

        mov     ax,map_offset
        add     ax,[width]        
        mov     map_offset,ax

        les     bx,[mapdata]
        add     bx,ax
        mov     ax,es:[bx]
        mov     cl,8
        shl     ax,cl
        add     si,ax

        dec     dx
        jnz     loop_tile

        pop si
        pop di
        pop ds
    }
```